# Springboot social using facebook for authorization

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social

Sorry if this is a VERY stupid question...

I'm new to Spring Security and I have a basic SpringBoot Rest API which I now want to learn how to secure.

Now what I really want to do is have separate webpage that does the "Login in with Facebook" view. But how do I secure some of the endpoints in my rest api using the token from facebook?

Imagine:

Endpoint /profile -- only the user who has logged in should be able to see their profile. Endpoint /welcome -- Everyone can access Endpoint /messages -- only the user who has logged in should be able to see their messages.

What frameworks should I be using here or how do i even go about doing this

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to OAuth (Open Authorization). There was a problem called "**Access Delegation Problem**"
at past, and OAuth was created to fix it. If you are able to access "Microservice Security In Action" book, it tells you exactly you want on Facebook example. (at **appendix D**)

In your scenario, here is the OAuth components.

- Resource Server: Your Spring Boot Project
- Authorization Server: Facebook
- Resource Owner: The end-user

First of all, import spring-security-oauth2 module to your project. Then configure spring security.

delegate your authentication to **Facebook** by **OpenID Connect / OIDC** (basically, authentication by OAuth 2.0)

```
http.oaut2Login()
```

Provide **authorization code** flow grant type details like client_id, redirect_uri, token_uri, authorize_uri.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
       ...
```

permit some urls to be public.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(preparePermittedUrls()).permitAll()
```